# Memory leak on flutter web when using Icon in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks

Consider this simple full application:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(body: MemoryTest()),
  ));
}

class MemoryTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const MemoryTest({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 500,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => const Icon(Icons.circle)
    );
  }
}
```

When running on web the memory keeps increasing indefinitely while scrolling through the list, as can seen in the Task Manager of Windows. Is this a bug in Flutter or how can I rewrite this code to prevent the memory leak? Simply replacing the `Icon` with a `Text` does not cause a leak.

Browser information:

```
Chrome Version 110.0.5481.180 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2604], locale en-DK)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.5.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

This happens both in debug and release builds

Comment: Have you tried this in release / profile build or debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on their github here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122189 and they pretty much confirmed that it's a bug in Flutter. For now a workaround is to use an older version of Flutter, version 3.3.10. That one doesn't have the memory leak